# Python APP OS error: failure reading sector 0x10e6c8 from hd0

Tags: hard-drive, grub, sata, operating-systems, bootloader

This is a Verifone Ruby2 POS. I have an Ubuntu boot flashdrive and another Ruby2 (main register).

My question is can I repair/recover the hd0 (which is 2GB solid-state SATA Flash)?
Or, copy Python App OS from other register to new SATA flash?

[image: Bootscreen]

[image: Bootscreen]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.